# Error response from daemon: Get https://nvcr.io/v2/: unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-docker

I begin to use NVIDIA GPU CLOUD Deep Learning platform. I try to pull in the console (Command Prompt):

```
docker pull nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:17.10
```

and get the message:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://nvcr.io/v2/: unauthorized: authentication required
```

What is my fault?

Comment: Hi Roman, I ran into similar issue. Does your docker work for the hello-world from docker hub? I had login issues there too. I set my docker DNS now to local LAN ip 192.168.178.1 in my case. Also I logged out(!) of docker console and successfully logged in again (using docker username). I am once again downloading containers from NVIDIA/NGC, so far so good...

Answer (score 16):

This error is an indication that the user is not authorized via login and API key. It is necessary to authorize in the console:

```
docker login nvcr.io

Username: $oauthtoken
Password: <Your Key>
```

You are not going to look for a special Username. $oauthtoken is the username.

Comment: Why would anyone set such a misleading username `$oauthtoken`? I wish I found this answer earlier and saved 20 min instead of bruteforcing login options

Comment: @Oleg, who knows? I would imagine a developer who wrote the first that he/she had in mind and went on :-)

Comment: Leaving this URL here for others: https://docs.nvidia.com/launchpad/ai/base-command-coe/latest/bc-coe-docker-basics-step-02.html

Answer (score 1):

docker login --username "$oauthtoken" --password "{REDACTED}" nvcr.io

I failed the above command, since it is pain to type password

Comment: Can you please explain your answer more.  How does this solve the OP's problem?

Comment: Agree with Ming, this is the only way how you could ever enter the API key. Trouble is, I get an error: "Error response from daemon: Get https://nvcr.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting fro connection Client.Time exceeded while awaiting header" or is it me again lacking some understanding?

Comment: For me "docker login nvcr.io" was giving me the error: "Error response from daemon: Get https://nvcr.io/v2/: unauthorized: authentication required". But trying to login with this method worked for me somehow. For anyone who may have the same problem like me.

Comment: I got same response?? Error response from daemon: Get https://nvcr.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Answer (score 0):

When run 'docker login', you just input '$oauthtoken' as your name. Not the nickname of your nvidia.NGC.